# Ordering of months in xaxis of Vega Lite plot

Tags: vega-lite

I have [this code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEDGD2B2AzAlgc0gLjKCFIDdkBTAd020gGcAXAJ1gGsjzI6BDeSgBzdqPmqQAvgBpwuSAFteDcsFaxYAG2rIucyCiJKAJiwCkkEVGoBPLsyyQAjgFcOq6m1X5mQ0eLy1bSyxRr0TAAibJQAFuQA2gDsxgCMALrGVHSMRADyPNDIZuQADAB0eQCsyShKSpls2blYeR64UGwAHsiUcp4SqLTIeliIbEqURGKNeEpsAEbaAILwqL75o2OQE9NKAGIIglaStsOwALSUHJSHAMx5eUad41PaWwIAysgAXn5xpbdQaw-bAOpENBhHZQeCwWjSJQ3MYmHK+R6gqT7IhHE6cC5XGErRwI7Yvd7kT7LRqseFERGA4FI8GQwaQTpCcQNKAAEko0DCRGkLBB1C4lAwAHoha5UGwCqgcmFbJMCshYEKOVzpKKiOLDkockRRQAWAoAK0oCGxkB0zjYGngbEkfjNFuEy1WbFMRFoUU6OBW0losiwXthrHMdq18GYJJWyAEbq4ymcdskCFg1AQ4e+eFjUdB8nKvj6YDothGUACaRYJDC2qMJbeHyuTNhLNJuL8AZxRGaSOxgY4nIhLEkvR0iwjpMQ2wHKLRp0x11HEnHz1r5AATHl53hYIhEMNQev01BF9QqagQSxaVCGY355B+HAdFH0P6DwplKp1FhIgeIDniLoDNWQYWCwdgODkzjIK4jrfhQWj-rsRB0Mg0CAWYwFWOCg7WtCDawmASQvs0HR4Quf75va1BpiReBoXalGSLGtD0huEiqLaACq8A5AO2wRCxeAtG0GgtuQ8A+EoySqNADAAMKwLYAg8QIfE-PcShzAsfj1AeTYrKYxHUZoZEAfxJjBiB9gCOBLhUYZgntP6ZLUL4AAa5CHMU9SmVQ0CDK2ZqwNIUZROuYCfHkCS4deL5wEo-bPtRh7GQhSEod5tHnoFUbMTBqzqvw+ZtiRzrrIik4HMcM6XHOMF3KV+LLlgxK1XCzl+GJFSmZu267qu+6JV4sAkAACmwOgPvM5DRAUxQwVFYzzRA826fIPp+lA3gjlAd6wBNT4UPpjn4IMRZTcUM3uLhBF4CQvTUBEWDRJ5TpctSfX9U0tgppQjUUBlGGptBGZjXtwmwB+YCXMkviIKCT3JD0p6giuz1QJMyYppI5DFMULIUaEiEOdgnT4x6sLyOalEsGucQAJyHHkAAcDNxIBtqpSwITIEophgHwcCuLQvOGMkhhNSu03RLpP4UXaNP03kCus8k7M9ChVhczzfNEALbrC4BYtgLT02M9LFCU3LeR04ccR5CzbOIWrnNsNzvP87Agv66LRKFFL84U-G1NW-TcRxPbKuO8hzuu9rutC2AItQIbcQAGwFCuZsB1TVjyzbK7h1AqtRxrLta+7nsJwbRK0wUfvfFnltrizBdSJH6tQJrbs6x7euV97WDnDXcSZy+FtB9bTPhy+Rft5Alw6Hzyihqgsc9-HIsvsneTTcUjPRIrKfRNEup0+cxS6t8I-FWPOfBwzSvdt6bcsPPi8VI+q8VxvxXJ58BS6rqc4QDgEgPOHES+-tR6B1vtbW2U9iozxfnkBe9B37zE-r3b+eFICGxTucAonxGZ5BTrqYoqc4grlpnkC+0Vyay3HiHMOVsHYcysK-VBy8MHryrlgGuu8r7YJvlAXOFD4HYMQWw5Bb9OHl0wY-UkhsVyM1rqfc+jNzh7wPtEc4ED65QOzsIvITcrZiMDBIqA7Cl4f1kdwliODVzTRTinChVDzgrhRkQlOs1GydASMyEAQggA) which uses year information in the dates but having the time unit as 'month' seems to force it to month ordering. This goes away if i switch to 'yearmonth', but is there a way to still only show the months but have the ordering based on the year information?

Comment: It's unclear to me how the code you linked to differs from what you want to see. It only shows months, and the months are ordered based on the year information.

Comment: I would like to maintain an ordering of the months based on their associated years, but not show the years on the xaxis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `month` timeUnit strips away all year information by design. If you want to keep the year information in the axis, you can use the `yearmonth` timeunit, and use an appropriate axis format string to hide the year (Vega-Lite's temporal format strings come from [d3-date-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format)).

Your x encoding might look something like this:

```
"x": {
  "field": "date",
  "type": "ordinal",
  "timeUnit": "yearmonth",
  "axis": {"title": null, "format": "%b"}
},
```